# how to resize icons in ionic framework v4 and Angular 7

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, icons

ngx-skycons is a library for icons

https://flexocarpius.github.io/ngx-skycons/demo

I'm trying to use this in the ionic project since it uses angular this icon lib is working fine but with one problem I can't resize icons.

This icon lib is port of https://github.com/darkskyapp/skycons

**Hear is a stackblitz for experiments https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyqwgu**

Comment: you can resize it by giving `width;height` to the `canvas`

Comment: setting up the canvas width height do not change anything. i used 

canvas {
    width: 10px;
 }
in app.component.scss

Comment: I have added stackblitz url in the question so you can test it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do deactivating the ViewEncapsulation. Look in the following example and for more informations read https://angular.io/guide/component-styles.

```
import { Component,ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
    export class AppComponent  {
      name = 'Skycons';
    }
```

best regards

Comment: I tried this but it didn't worked out please check the stackblitz and help me to identify the problem.

Comment: Your styles are the problem.Use  `sc-skycons canvas{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}`. Working Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxqern

Comment: this worked after changing the width and height of canvas when ViewEncapsulation is disabled